# Remote dimming in combination with glass wall switch

Tags: electrical

I'm looking for a way to control a dimmer remotely using one of those new fancy glass touch wall switches. I'm still free to choose any dimmer technology, altough I would prefer PWM dimming. This is for controlling an 12V/1A LED strip.

What I try to accomplish:

[image]

Most "Remote Control" wall switches control the switch remotely, not the "load".
The only two I've seen so far that *perhaps* may work are:

1) Sonoff RGB LED dimmer. Receiver is build into the under powered driver. Also not clear if it works with their wall switch.
https://sonoff.itead.cc/en/products/appliances/sonoff-led

2) KAKU (a Dutch 433mhz domotica system, sorry their website is only available in Dutch) which have a 433mhz sender which you can place behind a switch, which may work in conjunction with their receiver that can control a PWM input on a capable LED driver. I have sent an email to their support team, but I have doubts that this will play nicely together with those glass touch switches.

So basically I'm looking for products (or tips/hints/ideas) that can fulfil these requirements.

Comment: Why can you not run wires in this case?  Also, have you considered that it's possible to translate between various types of dimming signals? (PWM, 0-10V, phase-cut)

Comment: Beware:  Sonoff is Chinese junk; they haven't bothered having their stuff tested at a reputable testing lab, because they know it'll fail.  CE is not a testing lab.  You notice Sonoff stuff is direct-mailed from outside the EU (or via Amazon distribution). That's because CE is a *promise*: a legal commitment by the importer that it complies with safety standards.  When it's direct-mailed to you, **you're the importer**.

Comment: Welcome to Home Improvement! Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how better to contribute here.